# How do I compile Tor from source using MSYS on Windows?

Tags: compilation, compiler-errors, mingw, msys

I'm trying to compile tor 2.4.27 using MinGW's MSYS on Windows from source. I have built all the dependency libraries (libevent, libssl, libcrypto, libzlib) statically (.a files) from source and am now working on compiling the tor source itself.

I am using the following command within the msys.bat shell;

```
./configure --enable-static-tor --enable-static-libevent --with-libevent-dir=/projects/tor/libevent-2.0.22-stable
```

But no matter what I do the configure always stops with;

```
configure: WARNING: Could not find a linkable libevent. If you have installed it somewhere unusual, you can specify an explicit path using --with-libevent-dir
configure: error: Missing libraries; unable to proceed.
```

I have also tried the following;

```
./configure CFLAGS="-I/project/tor/libevent-2.0.22-stable/include" LDFLAGS="-L/project/tor/libevent-2.0.22-stable/" --enable-static-tor --enable-static-libevent
```

To no avail...

This is definitely a bug, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need `libevent-devel` for the headers.
It should compile fine after specifying the path with `--with-libevent-dir=`